# Convert Multile Objects to a single json

Tags: json, httprequest, object, http, serialization

I have a list of map and list objects. These objects needs to be sent as json content in an http request. 
The objects are

```
Map<String,String> leftFileParameters = new Map<String,String>();
    Map<String,String> rightFileParameters = new Map<String,String>();
    Map<String, Object> commonParameters  = new Map<String,Object>();

public void initiateParamas() {
        this.leftFileParameters.put('source_url',leftFile);     
        this.leftFileParameters.put('file_type','pdf');
        this.rightFileParameters.put('source_url',rightFile);
        this.rightFileParameters.put('file_type','pdf');
        this.commonParameters.put('public','false');
        this.commonParameters.put('expiry_time',validUntilTimeStamp);

    }
```

Now, I have a method as shown below. I want to serialize all the objects shown above and serialize it and set it as the body of request.

```
public String getURL(){
  initiateParams();
 HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
 req.setBody() //cannot serialize here.
}
```

So, How do i send all the objects as single json and send it in the http request body. Is there any class for doing that?

Answer (score 3):

This code will do what you require:

```
req.setBody(JSON.serialize(new Map<String, Object>{
    'left': leftFileParameters,
    'right': rightFileParameters,
    'common': commonParameters
}));
```

For more information, See the [JSON.serialize](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) method documentation. That method can work on maps and so the above code creates a map to hold the other maps. You can use whatever names you like instead of "left" etc.